# How can we prevent contact record overwrites once and for all?

Tags: civievent, duplicate-contacts, online-registration, drupal-7

I've been working with CiviCRM in Drupal for about 12 years and this issue never seems to go away entirely.

Someone, typically the president of an organization (just to make things more interesting) will register themselves and their spouse/partner for an event and one way or another they will overwrite their own record with their spouses name and add the email address of their spouse to their record.

Our registration profile is First Name, Last Name, Email Address and it is used for registering the first person and their guests.

**NOTE:** *We are allowing non-logged in people to register for events (not my decision).*

**My unsupervised rule for Individuals is:**

- Email: 15
- First name: 5
- Last name: 10
- Weight Threshold: 30

On my profile for event registration I have first name, last name and the email is set to "other" so as to prevent them overwriting the primary email address. I would have thought this would prevent overwriting but just this morning the president of an organization I support, managed to overwrite his contact record with his wife's name which of course shows up on any listing he's supposed to be on.

In order to try to combat this, I have unchecked the *"Same email address"* field for multiple registrations and I've added a new profile for guests which has First Name, Last Name as mandatory fields but the email field is not mandatory.

Other than making it mandatory for members to be logged in to register, I'm not sure what else we can do to prevent this from occurring.

Anyone else have ideas or solutions?

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: Is this happening to contacts who are registering from personalized links (i.e. with contact id and checksum in the URL) are is it just people registering through a non-personalized link?

Comment: Non personalized. It's self serve with no requirement to identify themselves.

Comment: OK, so are you ending up with two registrations for the same event on the same contact? Or do you have two contacts, with one registration each, and somehow the name and email for one of them has been switched? And is it the primary registrant who has their details switched?

Comment: And are you confident that the president wasn't logged in when he registered?

Comment: Thanks Lars, I'm ending up with two registrations and both of them get the same first name (their last name is the same). Both of them get the same email address which I have mapped to "other" in my registration fields profile. I am not sure if the president was logged in when he did this. If he was, then his name, email address and employer would have been pre-filled and he shouldn't have needed to do anything however if he went in logged-in, cleared the fields and registered his wife, I could see how that would get messy.

Comment: Sounds like maybe some kind of auto-fill situation on the president's end while logged in, perhaps, with their partner's name being filled in replacing their own when logged in. I can't see how this could happen other than while logged in given your dedupe rule. And then because you have the same email setting disabled, they came back to register a second time in a separate registration for the second one, but managed to put in the same name, perhaps? Not clear if you have one contact or two, but I'd think they'd be deduped into one.

Comment: I always leave same email enabled, because lots of people share an email address and just introduced more room for error if you force them to go through the process twice.

Comment: The more I consider it, the more I think he came in and was logged in. He probably registered himself and then came in again cleared the form fields and filled it in with his wife's details. I think your answer is as close as we're going to get so I will mark it as correct. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to try out the [No Overwrite extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite), which makes the contact's name read-only on forms. We've been using it for quite a while - it really helps cut down on this kind of problem.

We also use [Former Communications Data](https://civicrm.org/extensions/former-communication-data) to at least keep records of past emails if they are overwritten (though this extension is not infallible).